# Dynamically create document chapters based on directory tree

Tags: sectioning, chapters, compiling, sections-paragraphs

For creating document structure I usually use something like this:

```
\section{1}
  Text for chapter 1

\section{2}
  Text for chapter 2

  \subsection{2.1}
  Text for chapter 2.1

    \subsubsection{2.1.1}
      Text for chapter 2.1.1

      \paragraph{2.1.1.1}\mbox{}\\
      Text for chapter 2.1.1.1
```

Is it possible to automatically handle `\section \subsection \subsubsection\paragraph ...` based on directory structure? My idea is to have tree like directory structure which will serve as template for document creation. In this example desired text `"Text for chapter ..."` is inside `chapter.tex` files:

```
./1/chapter.tex
./2/chapter.tex
./2/2.1/chapter.tex
./2/2.1/2.1.1/chapter.tex
./2/2.1/2.1.1/2.1.1.1/chapter.tex
```

Following example is same as previous except desired text is contained in files which has different names (one file per each directory). This is better because in your editor you can see correct names of chapters instead of `chapter.txt` for each document section:

```
./1/1.tex
./2/2.tex
./2/2.1/2_1.tex
./2/2.1/2.1.1/2_1_1.tex
./2/2.1/2.1.1/2.1.1.1/2_1_1_1.tex
```

As a bonus I would also like automatic labeling of chapters under each `\section \subsection \subsubsection\paragraph ...`, something like `\label{2.1.1}` etc.

I guess that I need some kind of preprocessor which will first sort alphabetically resp numerically underlining directories and compose final document. I'm not sure if this LaTeX can do or some external tools are required. Multiplatform solution would be fine but my primary OS is Linux. Thank you.

Comment: This means that manually set the sectioning numbers?

Comment: Yes and no. You can have e.g. 2.1.1 or b.a.a and it should result in same order. Important is only alphabetical or numeric (or some other) order. Based on chosen order appropriate document structure should be generated. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Please help us help you, in `./2/2.1/2.1.1/2_1_1.tex` for example the `2_1_1` is the file name and it is the chapter or (sub)section heading?

Comment: @touhami the idea is to have tree like directory structure. Based on this structure appropriate chapter/(sub)sections will be generated. All three code snippets that I've posted are equivalent. So `2_1_1.tex` should translate to`\subsubsection{2.1.1}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution

**Notes**

1. The solution use (la)TeX loop.
2. File names changed 1_1_1 -->1+1+1 (this is easier)

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\newif\ifmoreinput
\newcounter{sec}
\newcounter{ssec}[sec]
\newcounter{sssec}[ssec]
\newcounter{parg}[sssec]
\begin{document}
\loop
\stepcounter{section}%
\stepcounter{sec}%
\edef\mtpath{\thesection}%
\edef\mtfile{\thesec}%
\IfFileExists{\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}{%
\moreinputtrue%
\addtocounter{section}{-1}%
\let\SomeMagicCommandThatHoldsChapterNameGoesHere\section
\input{\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}%
{\loop
\stepcounter{subsection}%
\stepcounter{ssec}%
\edef\mtpath{\thesection/\thesubsection}%
\edef\mtfile{\thesec+\thessec}%
\IfFileExists{\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}{%
\moreinputtrue%
\addtocounter{subsection}{-1}%
\let\SomeMagicCommandThatHoldsChapterNameGoesHere\subsection
\input{\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}%
{\loop
\stepcounter{subsubsection}%
\stepcounter{sssec}%
\edef\mtpath{\thesection/\thesubsection/\thesubsubsection}%
\edef\mtfile{\thesec+\thessec+\thesssec}%
\IfFileExists{\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}{%
\moreinputtrue%
\addtocounter{subsubsection}{-1}%
\let\SomeMagicCommandThatHoldsChapterNameGoesHere\subsubsection
\input{\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}%
{\loop
\stepcounter{paragraph}%
\stepcounter{parg}%
\edef\mtpath{\thesection/\thesubsection/\thesubsubsection/\theparagraph}%
\edef\mtfile{\thesec+\thessec+\thesssec+\theparg}%
\IfFileExists{\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}{%
\moreinputtrue%
\addtocounter{paragraph}{-1}%
\let\SomeMagicCommandThatHoldsChapterNameGoesHere\paragraph
\input{\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}}{\moreinputfalse}%
\ifmoreinput\repeat}}{\moreinputfalse}%
\ifmoreinput\repeat}}{\moreinputfalse}%
\ifmoreinput\repeat}}{\moreinputfalse}%
\ifmoreinput\repeat

\end{document}
```

---

**Update** here a better way: we use `makemymain.tex` to produce `mymain.tex`
this new file will be well strectured and more helpfull with latex editor (I will try to explain as i can)

**makemymain.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\newcommand{\SomeMagicCommandThatHoldsChapterNameGoesHere}[1]{{#1}}

\newread\mtread
\newwrite\mtwrite
\immediate\openout\mtwrite=mymain.tex

\newcommand{\mtadd}[1]{\immediate\write\mtwrite{\string#1}}
\newcommand{\mtinput}[1]{%
\moreinputtrue%
\openin\mtread=\mtpath/\mtfile.tex
\read\mtread to \myread
\closein\mtread
\immediate\write\mtwrite{\string#1\myread}
\immediate\write\mtwrite{\string\input {\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}}}

% creating preamble of mymain.tex
\mtadd{\documentclass{article}}
\mtadd{\usepackage{lipsum}}
\mtadd{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}}
\mtadd{\newcommand{\string\SomeMagicCommandThatHoldsChapterNameGoesHere}[1]{}}
\mtadd{\begin{document}}

\AtEndDocument{\mtadd{\end{document}}}

\newif\ifmoreinput
\newcounter{sec}
\newcounter{ssec}[sec]
\newcounter{sssec}[ssec]
\newcounter{parg}[sssec]
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\loop
\stepcounter{section}%
\stepcounter{sec}%
\edef\mtpath{\thesection}%
\edef\mtfile{\thesec}%
\IfFileExists{\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}{%
\mtinput{\section}%
{\loop
\stepcounter{subsection}%
\stepcounter{ssec}%
\edef\mtpath{\thesection/\thesubsection}%
\edef\mtfile{\thesec+\thessec}%
\IfFileExists{\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}{%
\mtinput{\subsection}%
{\loop
\stepcounter{subsubsection}%
\stepcounter{sssec}%
\edef\mtpath{\thesection/\thesubsection/\thesubsubsection}%
\edef\mtfile{\thesec+\thessec+\thesssec}%
\IfFileExists{\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}{%
\mtinput{\subsubsection}%
{\loop
\stepcounter{paragraph}%
\stepcounter{parg}%
\edef\mtpath{\thesection/\thesubsection/\thesubsubsection/\theparagraph}%
\edef\mtfile{\thesec+\thessec+\thesssec+\theparg}%
\IfFileExists{\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}{%
\mtinput{\paragraph}}{\moreinputfalse}%
\ifmoreinput\repeat}}{\moreinputfalse}%
\ifmoreinput\repeat}}{\moreinputfalse}%
\ifmoreinput\repeat}}{\moreinputfalse}%
\ifmoreinput\repeat

\end{document}
```

---

**Update 2**
To avoid problems of expansion (read--write)

```
\newcommand{\SomeMagicCommandThatHoldsChapterNameGoesHere}[1]{{#1}}
```

replaced with

```
\newcommand{\SomeMagicCommandThatHoldsChapterNameGoesHere}[1]{{\unexpanded{#1}}}
```

back to original convention of files names `2_1_1.tex`:

```
\catcode`\_12\relax
```

add before first loop

**makemymain.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\SomeMagicCommandThatHoldsChapterNameGoesHere}[1]{{\unexpanded{#1}}}

\newread\mtread
\newwrite\mtwrite
\immediate\openout\mtwrite=mymain.tex

\newcommand{\mtadd}[1]{\immediate\write\mtwrite{\string#1}}
\newcommand{\mtinput}[1]{%
\moreinputtrue%
\openin\mtread=\mtpath/\mtfile.tex
\read\mtread to \myread
\closein\mtread
\immediate\write\mtwrite{\string#1\myread}
\immediate\write\mtwrite{\string\input {\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}^^J}}

% creating preamble of mymain.tex
\mtadd{\documentclass{article}}
\mtadd{\usepackage{lipsum}}
\mtadd{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}}
\mtadd{\newcommand{\string\SomeMagicCommandThatHoldsChapterNameGoesHere}[1]{}}
\mtadd{\begin{document}}

\AtEndDocument{\mtadd{\end{document}}}

\newif\ifmoreinput
\newcounter{sec}
\newcounter{ssec}[sec]
\newcounter{sssec}[ssec]
\newcounter{parg}[sssec]
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\catcode`\_12\relax
\loop
\stepcounter{section}%
\stepcounter{sec}%
\def\mtpath{\thesection}%
\def\mtfile{\thesec}%
\IfFileExists{\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}{%
\mtinput{\section}%
{\loop
\stepcounter{subsection}%
\stepcounter{ssec}%
\def\mtpath{\thesection/\thesubsection}%
\def\mtfile{\thesec_\thessec}%
\IfFileExists{\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}{%
\mtinput{\subsection}%
{\loop
\stepcounter{subsubsection}%
\stepcounter{sssec}%
\def\mtpath{\thesection/\thesubsection/\thesubsubsection}%
\def\mtfile{\thesec_\thessec_\thesssec}%
\IfFileExists{\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}{%
\mtinput{\subsubsection}%
{\loop
\stepcounter{paragraph}%
\stepcounter{parg}%
\def\mtpath{\thesection/\thesubsection/\thesubsubsection/\theparagraph}%
\def\mtfile{\thesec_\thessec_\thesssec_\theparg}%
\IfFileExists{\mtpath/\mtfile.tex}{%
\mtinput{\paragraph}}{\moreinputfalse}%
\ifmoreinput\repeat}}{\moreinputfalse}%
\ifmoreinput\repeat}}{\moreinputfalse}%
\ifmoreinput\repeat}}{\moreinputfalse}%
\ifmoreinput\repeat

\end{document}
```

**mymain.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\newcommand{\SomeMagicCommandThatHoldsChapterNameGoesHere}[1]{}
\begin{document}
\section{chapter 1} 
\input{1/1.tex}

\section{chapter 2} 
\input{2/2.tex}

\subsection{chapter 2.1} 
\input{2/2.1/2_1.tex}

\subsubsection{chapter 2.1.1} 
\input{2/2.1/2.1.1/2_1_1.tex}

\paragraph{chapter 2.1.1.1} 
\input{2/2.1/2.1.1/2.1.1.1/2_1_1_1.tex}

\subsection{chapter 2.2} 
\input{2/2.2/2_2.tex}

\subsubsection{chapter 2.2.1} 
\input{2/2.2/2.2.1/2_2_1.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The structure that you've posted is correct but some other important thing comes to my mind: I also need way to tell chapter name to which  `2_1_1.tex` should translate to. Best way I can imagine is to have some tag for chapter/(sub)section name right inside `2_1_1.tex`. E.g.: if content of `2_1_1.tex` is: `\SomeMagicCommandThatHoldsChapterNameGoesHere{Chapter name goes here} Text for chapter 2.1.1` then it will translate to `\subsubsection{Chapter name goes here} Text for chapter 2.1.1`. I hope you get the point.

Comment: @WakanTanka exactly that is!

Comment: @WakanTanka answer updated.

Comment: seems that it does not work for me as expected. It only creates chapter 1 and 2 without any (sub)chapters/(sub)sections. Project is here http://www.filedropper.com/latex

Comment: oh I did not noticed file name change from `1_1_1.tex` to `1+1+1.tex` Seems that it is working now. PS: is it possible to also combine it with another LaTeX commands e.g. glossaries etc.? PPS: why is `1+1+1.tex` convention more easy to implement? Can you please recommend some resources from where I can study more about your approach? Thank you.

Comment: `_` is special character used in math mode so using it need more care. If i havetime i will update my answer, the idea is to run latex in the file (this file will be considered as make or bash) to produce new file that will be used as main.tex.

Comment: @WakanTanka answer updated.

Comment: @WakanTanka please see update 2.

Answer (score 2):

This approach may not be a good idea, LaTeX is designed to take care of the numbering for you (for example when you decide later to add a section between 1 and 2).

If you want to do it anyway, a scripting language is probably the easiest way. Example in Perl:

```perl
use File::Find;
use Cwd;
# get working directory for script
$cwd1 = getcwd();

# find all tex files recursively, store the path relative to cwd1
find(sub{ push(@allfiles,substr(getcwd(),length($cwd1))."/".$_) if $_=~/tex$/; },'.');

# sort the file list to get the right order
# note: tex files are called 0chapter.tex for sorting purposes
foreach $file(sort @allfiles){
    # count the number of underscores minus 2 (/1/0chapter.tex is level 0)
    $strlevel = "sub" x (($file =~ tr#/#/#)-2);
    # read the file
    open(IN,"<$cwd1$file");
    chomp(@contents = <IN>);
    close(IN);
    # print the first line of the file as (subsubsub)section title and the rest as contents
    print "\\$strlevel"."section\{$contents[0]\}\n".join("\n",@contents[1..$#contents])."\n";
    close(IN);
}
```

Add in a `\newcommand{\subsubsubsection}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}` somewhere and you are set. Example output from this script, using your directory structure:

```
\section{Title of foo}
contents of foo
\section{Title of bar}
contents of bar
\subsection{Title of foobar}
contents of foobar
\subsubsection{Title of foobarbaz}
contents of foobarbaz
\subsubsubsection{Title of foobarbazqux}
contents of foobarbazqux
```

Comment: @Marijin I understand the pitfalls of this solution but my main idea is to separate all chapters/(sub)sections to standalone files. If I want to later swap chapters I just swap the appropriate files. I do not understand the part about `\newcommand{\subsubsubsection}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}` that you've mentioned. Also I need to make it more robust because I would like to have one `main.tex` and from this file somehow "load" files in given tree structure and generate appropriate chapters/(sub)sections. I guess using `make` or `cmake` would be the best option but I'm not sure.